# Add a link to the chat user pop-out menu: "user profile on this site"

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, users

See this link?

[image]

This link doesn't presently exist. I'm here to request its addition, so that visiting someone's profile on the same site as the one you're chatting on won't be a potentially long path.

If I'm chatting, and a user's profile is linked to the same site as the one the chat room belongs to, it's pretty simple to visit their profile. However,  consider this situation:

- I am on a chat room belonging to [Role-Playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
- There is a user in there whose RPG.SE profile I would like to see
- The user's parent profile belongs to a site other than RPG.SE

In this situation, the path to getting to their RPG.SE profile (if they have one) can be a long path.

### The current path when their parent profile is on another SE site

> #### 1. Click the parent user link
>
> [image]
>
> #### 2. Arrive at their parent profile
>
> [image]
>
> #### 3. Scroll down, find the site in question, click
>
> [image]
>
> #### Goal!
>
> [image]

### The current path when their RPG.SE profile is not in their top 5

> #### 1. Click the parent user link
>
> [image]
>
> #### 2. Arrive at their parent profile
>
> [image]
>
> #### 3. Scroll down to the accounts list. RPG.SE isn't there; click 'view more'
>
> [image]
>
> #### 4. Arrive at their global Stack Exchange profile
>
> [image]
>
> #### 5. Scroll down or ctrl+f, find the site, click
>
> [image]
>
> #### Goal!
>
> [image]

Both of these paths would be replaced with one the same length as if their parent user matched the site the chat is on: pop open that menu, click the link.

Comment: What should happen if the user doesn't have a profile on the given site?

Comment: @Monica It should probably not show up at all.

Answer (score 7):

I've written a userscript to accomplish this.

#### [GitHub link.](https://gist.github.com/Seth-Johnson/7445b149cf980e992e8a) [Direct link.](https://gist.github.com/Seth-Johnson/7445b149cf980e992e8a/raw/9f172c75007e1d8097f6f713ac67cf96dd04f726/userscript.user.js)

If it doesn't work initially for you try increasing the timeout on line 105. If you find any bugs please let me know!

> [image: has profile]

If you're in a network chat room (ones that aren't attached to any site) it will instead link to the user's network profile.

> [image: network profile]

If the user has no profile it will tell you that as well.

> [image: no profile]

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Chat site profiler thingy
// @namespace   http://askubuntu.com/users/44179
// @include     *chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     *chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     *chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

    var networkID = "";
    var userID = "";
    var userBaseSite = "";
    var userBaseSiteID = "";
    var siteProfile = "";
    var mainSiteURL = $('#footer-logo > a').attr('href');
    var baseUserURL = mainSiteURL + "/users/";
    var mainSiteName = $('#footer-logo > a').attr('title').replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    var json;

    function getAssocAccounts(pageNum) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/" + networkID + "/associated?page=" + pageNum +  "&pagesize=100&filter=!*L2(U8cAI.NDVpWE", false);
        xhr.send();

        return xhr.response;
    }

    function findLocalProfile(data) {
        for (var item in data.items) {
            if (data.items[item].site_name == mainSiteName || data.items[item].site_name == mainSiteName + " Stack Exchange") {
                console.log(data.items[item].site_name);
                userID = data.items[item].user_id;
                siteProfile = "<a href='" + baseUserURL + userID + "'> user profile on this site </a>";
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function setSiteProfile() {
        if (mainSiteName == "The Stack Exchange Network") {
            siteProfile = "<a href='" + baseUserURL + networkID + "?tab=accounts" + "'> network profile </a>";
        }
        else {
            var json =  JSON.parse(getAssocAccounts(1));
            if (findLocalProfile(json)) {
                return;
            }
            json = JSON.parse(getAssocAccounts(2));
            if (findLocalProfile(json)) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                siteProfile = "<a> user has no profile on site </a>";
            }
        }
    }

    function setNetworkID() {
        userBaseSite = $('.user-popup').find('div:contains("user profile on") > a').attr('href').split('/')[2].split('.')[0];
        userBaseSiteID = $('.user-popup').find("a:contains('user profile')")[1].href.split("/")[4];

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/" + userBaseSiteID + "?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=" + userBaseSite + "&filter=!23IbozPckvHAbU7zwAs_E", false);
        xhr.send();

        var response = xhr.response;
        var json = JSON.parse(response);
        networkID = json.items[0].account_id;
        console.log(networkID);
    }

    function doIt() {
        if ($('.user-popup').length > 0) {
            setNetworkID();
            setSiteProfile();
            console.log("inserting link");
            $('.user-popup').find('div:contains("user profile")').next().eq(0).after(siteProfile);
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log("No popup");
        }
    }

    $('.avatar, #chat').click(function() {
        // if it doesn't work initially, try increasing the timeout (default: 300)
        window.setTimeout(doIt, 300);
    });
```